# import static vs. static final

Tags: java, performance, memory, import, constants

In the past I often used "import static" construct in Java classes. Recently I realized that instead of

```
import static my.pack.A.MY_CONSTANT;
```

you can use

```
import my.pack.A;

public class B {
    private static final MY_CONSTANT = A.MY_CONSTANT;
}
```

The most obvious advantages of this approach are:

1. You can use refactoring in Eclipse to easily strip out all long constant expressions like `A.B.C.CONSTANT.ANOTHER_ONE.TOO_LONG` from your code without messing with static imports (which are not so quick to master in Eclipse)
2. You can give any name to any expression, which may be more meaningful in the current context.

For example:

```
private static final PAYMENT_TYPE = PaymentType.CASH;
...
calculateSomething(amount, PAYMENT_TYPE);
```

instead of

```
import static my.pack.PaymentType.CASH
...
calculateSomething(amount, CASH);
```

and also this is more easy to refactor, if the default PaymentType value changes to CREDIT_CARD.

My question is: are there any downsides of this approach compared to static imports or can it be used everywhere instead?

My only concern for now is the resulting compiled .class file, which is probably different for the two described approaches. So performance and memory usage may theoretically suffer.

Comment: Have you thought about using Enums instead? They seem more appropriate in this situation.

Comment: Not sure, how enums solve my problem of importing some existing constants into my class file. Actually, the enum's values can be imported in either way, similar to constants.

Comment: Are you able to compile both versions, decompile and compare the difference?

Comment: Too abstract. PaymentType looks like the interface-constant antipattern.

Comment: Well Enums do not need static imports, they are implicitly static.

Comment: @Peter Rader how do you see that PaymentType is not an enum in my example?

Comment: @Tom Cammann isn't "CASH" more readable than "NonBankRelatedAccountTypes.CASH", if it is used 10 times in one class?

Comment: @nucleo, i guessed :D ... is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the only downside is you have more code where you assign one constant to another constant. Other than that there should be no difference. Performance and memory shouldn't matter, you'll likely have more references back to the same constant pool entries. Even if it created separate constant pool entries it would take a lot of them to make a difference.

Being able to give good names to constants might be a very good thing, in cases where it isn't feasible to rename the original entries.

Answer (score 3):

It is mostly a matter of taste, but the official [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) recommend using the `static` version sparingly, especially with a wildcard.  The main downside of static import is that it pollutes your namespace by added all the static members to it.  In your above example, it should be about what you think it more readable for your code. Resist the urge to do "import package.*" unless you really want all the `static` members of `package`.

It should not effect your compiled code -- it is merely provides a shorthand access to the same constant.

Comment: I tend to do static imports, when I know for sure that the imported constant has some meaning in the context of the class that imports it. "import static my.pack.PaymentType.*" is easily and automatically converted to "import static my.pack.PaymentType.CASH" in IDE. I even have this action bound to saving the file. This is also an advantage of "static final" - because it has more meaningful name in the context of client class.